# PHP (NETTE) -> Group array of object by object value

Tags: php, arrays, nette

I'm using NETTE and I get data ( object ) from database.
For example:

```
array{ 
   [0]=> object{ ["CestyNazev"]=> "K00301" ["datum"]=> "2018-03-27"
   [1]=> object( ["CestyNazev"]=> "K00302" ["datum"]=> "2018-03-27"
   [2]=> object( ["CestyNazev"]=> "KLA101" ["datum"]=> "2018-03-26"
   [3]=> object( ["CestyNazev"]=> "KLA102" ["datum"]=> "2018-03-29"
}
```

And I want to group it by Date so result should be (array):

```
**2018-03-27**
K00301
K00302

**2018-03-26**
KLA101

**2018-03-29**
KLA102
```

Can you help me please?

Comment: Nice idea. Do it! Jokes aside – what is your problem in doing so? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Did you read this article? https://doc.nette.org/cs/2.0/database#toc-table-selection-api

Comment: I had Idea to use. `->fetchPairs("datum");`  But it's return only one data for each date. So when I have more data for one date(datum) it's return only one of them.

Answer (score 0):

This is general solution for create multidimentional array from select. Write for using in model or presenter.

```
$table = $database->table->select('datum, CestyNazev');

$result = [];

foreach ($table as $value) {
    if (array_key_exists($value->datum, $result)) {
        array_push($result[$value->datum], $value->CestyNazev);
    } else {
        $result[$value->datum] = [$value->CestyNazev];
    }
}
```

result

```
array (3)
    2018-03-27 => array (2)
        0 => K00301
        1 => K00302
    2018-03-26 => array (1)
        0 => KLA101
    2018-03-29 => array (1)
        0 => KLA102
```